# Directory files into comma separated values in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have directory @"c:\dom\" where I have more than 100 excel files.
I need to return all the excel file path in below format(CSV)

`@"C:\dom\dom1.xlsx",
@"C:\dom\dom2.xlsx",
@"C:\dom\dom3.xlsx",
.
.
.
@"C:\dom\dom100.xlsx"`

I tried the below

```
 string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\dom\");
 foreach (string name in array1)
 {
    string.Join(",", name);
 }
```

It didn't work out.

Answer (score 4):

The following enumerates the files then concat them as a CSV string.

```
var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\dom\");
var csv = String.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, filePaths);
```

Please note that if you do not need the trailing comma, you can modify the Join like this:

```
var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\dom\");
var csv = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, filePaths);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple ugly solution:

```
    string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\dom\");
    string csv = String.Empty;
    foreach (string name in array1.Where(x => x.EndsWith("xlsx")))
        csv += name + ",\r\n";
```

Comment: this will create a comma after value rather than comma separated value

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason your code didn't work is because you missed out a variable to store the result that was returned from the line `string.Join(",", name);`

So it's definitely not an issue with using `Directory.GetFiles()`.

Anyway all you need is actually no more than 1 line of code.

```
// to export it into a csv file (1 entry per row)
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\output.csv", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\dom\")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function, and just put your folder path as the requested parameters

```
    public static string GetFilePathConcenated(string folderPath)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(folderPath){
            string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
            return string.Join(",", fileList).TrimEnd(',');
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```